# How can I parse same named XML element contents in Linux?

Tags: xml, linux, parsing

**Hello everyone. I'm trying to write a script that edits an xml file. Unfortunately there same named tags in file like:**

```
<phase1>
 <ikeid>1</ikeid>
 <iketype>ikev1</iketype>
 <mode>main</mode>
 <myid_type>myaddress</myid_type>
 <myid_data/>
 <peerid_type>peeraddress</peerid_type>
 <peerid_data/>
 <lifetime>28800</lifetime>
 <pre-shared-key>lol</pre-shared-key>
</phase1>

<phase1>
 <ikeid>2</ikeid>
 <iketype>ikev1</iketype>
 <mode>main</mode>
 <myid_type>any</myid_type>
 <myid_data/>
 <peerid_type>address</peerid_type>
 <peerid_data/>
 <lifetime>20000</lifetime>
 <pre-shared-key>lel</pre-shared-key>
</phase1>
```

**I need to reach those two "phase1" blocks seperately and edit them using xmllint. Briefly, I want an output like:**

```
<phase1>
 <ikeid>1</ikeid>
 <iketype>ikev1</iketype>
 <mode>main</mode>
 <myid_type>myaddress</myid_type>
 <myid_data/>
 <peerid_type>peeraddress</peerid_type>
 <peerid_data/>
 <lifetime>28800</lifetime>
 <pre-shared-key>lol</pre-shared-key>
</phase1>

<phase1>
 <ikeid> I EDITTED THIS PART</ikeid>
 <iketype>ikev1</iketype>
 <mode>THIS IS ALSO EDITTED</mode>
 <myid_type>any</myid_type>
 <myid_data/>
 <peerid_type>address</peerid_type>
 <peerid_data/>
 <lifetime>HELP</lifetime>
 <pre-shared-key>lel</pre-shared-key>
</phase1>
```

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Like below:

```
xmllint --shell file.xml
cd /some/path/phase1[ikeid='1']/lifetime
```

This command reaches "lifetime" element of "phase1" which contains "ikeid" value 1.